# How do I unset an element in an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I remove the key 'bar' from an array foo so that 'bar' won't show up in

```
for(key in foo){alert(key);}
```

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Don't use **delete** as it won't remove an element from an array it will only set it as undefined, which will then not be reflected correctly in the length of the array.

If you know the key you should use **splice** i.e.

```
myArray.splice(key, 1);
```

For someone in Steven's position you can try something like this:

```
for (var key in myArray) {
    if (key == 'bar') {
        myArray.splice(key, 1);
    }
}
```

or

```
for (var key in myArray) {
    if (myArray[key] == 'bar') {
        myArray.splice(key, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Good point, I also like this way: http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Care to explain? I don't know what that means and keen to learn. As always, an edit is a 1,000,000 times better than an off-hand comment; you should know that with the amount of rep you have.

Comment: Use `for (var key in myArray)` instead of `for (key in myArray)` - otherwise `key` is a global variable and if you call a function inside that loop that has the same problem, you will get unexpected results.

Comment: Note, the second example doesn't work if the array has multiple items in a row that match 'bar'. The index of the array will shift and you will miss splicing half of the items. Instead, use a for loop that decrements the index when a match is found.

Comment: For an array of objects : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property

Comment: Just a reminder not to try to delete array elements using `splice()` when looking in an array using the array index as the key. Splicing will shorten the array, but the loop may still count up to the previous length of the array.

Comment: Why is this the accepted answer, it only works when the key it's numeric. The accepted answer should be `delete yourArray[key];` and that statement about making it undefined it's false

Comment: Given that the OP hasn't shown us how `foo` was created, it could be an array or an object. The best answer I've seen is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173210/delete-vs-splice-on-associative-array

Comment: I like this way:  myArray.splice(myArray.indexOf('bar'),1)

Comment: use `for(var key=myArray.length-1;key>=0;key--)` to avoid problems with index shifting. works with numeric keys only

Answer (score 68):

```
delete foo[key];
```

:D

Comment: technically that doesn't answer the question. he's looking to remove the key 'bar'. and your key variable doesn't imply that. :P

Comment: key='bar'; eval("delete foo."+key);  *hides* ;D

Comment: Do *NOT* use `eval`. Deleting a key/index of an object/array can be achieved by much simpler methods not using `eval`.

Comment: Actually if you remove from indexed array by delete foo[key] it will stores value in foo[key]=undefined and foo.length will remain same which is wrong. So use SPLICE instead

Comment: use delete foo[key] it wrong;   
should use foo.splice(key, 1);

Answer (score 43):

If you know the key name simply do like this:

```
delete array['key_name']
```

Comment: This is not an array! It's an object (yes, these are called associative arrays in JS, but no, they aren't really, and this method is harmful if you trully work with a JS array).

Answer (score 38):

An important note: JavaScript Arrays are not associative arrays like those you might be used to from PHP. If your "array key" is a string, you're no longer operating on the contents of an array. Your array is an object, and you're using bracket notation to access the member named <key name>. Thus:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray["bar"] = true;
myArray["foo"] = true;
alert(myArray.length); // returns 0.
```

because you have not added elements to the array, you have only modified myArray's bar and foo members.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I would do it

```
 myArray.splice( myArray.indexOf('bar') , 1)
```

Comment: The Array.prototype.indexOf() method searches for a value within an array, not for a key. So this will not work.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.internetdoc.info/javascript-function/remove-key-from-array.htm

```
removeKey(arrayName,key);

function removeKey(arrayName,key)
{
 var x;
 var tmpArray = new Array();
 for(x in arrayName)
 {
  if(x!=key) { tmpArray[x] = arrayName[x]; }
 }
 return tmpArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is an important difference between delete and splice:

ORIGINAL ARRAY:

[<1 empty item>, 'one',<3 empty items>, 'five', <3 empty items>,'nine']

AFTER SPLICE (array.splice(1,1)):

[ <4 empty items>, 'five', <3 empty items>, 'nine' ]

AFTER DELETE (delete array[1]):

[ <5 empty items>, 'five', <3 empty items>, 'nine' ]