# What's wrong with my remove function?

Tags: javascript

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === obj) {
            if (i == this.length) {
                this[i] = null;
            } else {
                for(var j = i; j < this.length-1; j++) {
                    this[j] = this[j+1];
                }
                delete this[j]; // updated from this[j] = null; still not working.
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

calling it with:

```
write("ARRAY TEST = " + [22, 33, 44].remove(33).remove(22));
```

..it prints:

```
44,,
```

Why this 2 commas and how to fix my remove function to remove the commas as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete` on an `Array` will not remove the element, it will set it to `undefined`. And since `undefined` when printed results in an empty string, that explains the results of `write()`.

You need to use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove the element. If you combine it with [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Compatibility) (you may need to define it for older browser) you get a pretty short function:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (obj) {
    this.splice(this.indexOf(obj), 1);
    return this;
}
```

PS: I'm not an advocate of expanding native prototypes...

Comment: It works, thaks! I just thought it strange that [this doc](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) says that slice second arg is "end", not "length" as it actually is.

Comment: @Tom For future reference stick to MDN, w3schools is outdated and has a lot of misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the item to null leaves an item in the array (but it is a null item), which is why you see the commas still.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, deleting or setting the item to null still leaves the item in the array. What you want to use is Array.splice

Here's an implementation that should work:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
       if(this[i] === obj)
       {
           this.splice(i,1);
           break;
       }       
    }
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't remove the elements from the array you just set them to null.
If you need inspiration look at this remove method. It's by index and not by element.

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-array-remove/

try:

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === obj) {
            if (i == this.length) {
                this.splice(i,1);
            } else {
                for(var j = i; j < this.length-1; j++) {
                    this[j] = this[j+1];
                }
                this.splice(j,1);
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Array.prototype.remove = function (obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if(this[i] === obj) {
            if (i == this.length) {
                #this[i] = null;
                delete this[i];
            } else {
                for(var j = i; j < this.length-1; j++) {
                    this[j] = this[j+1];
                }
                #this[j] = null;
                delete this[i];
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
};
```

Pretty sure that is what you want

Comment: I think you mean `delete this[j]`, but it don't work, the commas are still there..

Comment: -1 delete does not remove the element from the array (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206988/how-do-i-unset-an-element-in-an-array-in-javascript)