# Delete vs splice on associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

If I have a JS associative array which is from what I gather is really an object, and I wish to remove an element, using `delete myArr[someId]` will set the element to undefined, whilst splice won't work at all... so what is the alternative for an associative array if I wish to delete an element (rather than setting it to `undefined`)

Comment: Why delete it? What is it hurting being in there? `undefined` is as good as it gets. You can make up a property for an established object and check its type, it will be `undefined`.

Comment: Are you asking the difference between `delete myArray[someID]` and `myArray[someID]=undefined`? If so, I think the former is better as the latter will lead to problems when checking for `undefined`

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The terminology in js can be confusing at first, so lets straighten that out first.

Yes, pretty much everything in js is an object. However, there are differences in the data types.

An array can be used *like* as associative array, but its different than an object literal.

```
var x = []; //array
var y = {}; //object literal
```

An array is like a list. The keys of an array can be a numerical index or a string.

```
var x = ['a','b']; // x[0] === 'a', x[1] === 'b';
var x = [];
    x['one'] = 'a';
    x['blah'] = 'b';
```

Object literals are like dictionaries. They can be used in a similar way.

```
var x = { 0: 'a', 1: 'b' };
var x = { one: 'a', two: 'b' };
```

However, this is where you need to understand the differences.

You can use an array *like* an object literal, but you can't use an object literal quite like an array.

Arrays have the automated "length" property, This increments and decrements automatically based on the total number of elements in the array. You don't get this with object literals. Arrays also get all of the other array-specific methods like shift, unshift, splice, pop, push, etc. Object literals don't have those methods.

Lets talk about delete and what happens on an array and on an object literal.

```
var x = ['a', 'b']; //["a", "b"]
delete x[0]; //[undefined, "b"]

var x = {0:'1', 1:'b'}// { 0:"1", 1:"b"}
delete x[0]; // { 1:"b" }
```

If you perform a delete on an element of an array, the length of the array doesn't change. The element index is preserved and the value is set to 'undefined';

Conversely, performing a delete on an object literal removes the key/value from the object.

Finally, if you want to remove an element from an array.

```
var x = ['a', 'b']; 
x.splice(0,1); //modifies x. ['b']
```

So, in summary use delete on object literals. Use splice on arrays.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Splicing an array when items are defined one by one does not work...  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896167/nodejs-array-splice-associate-array-does-not-work I am trying to understand what's happening here...

Comment: !!! lets reconsider for arrays: http://jsperf.com/delete-vs-splice

looks like Chrome 36 does the delete faster now, "Just in Time Compilation" helps here.

Comment: @sushicutta the problem is not speed, the problem is what the length of the array is after removal.

Answer (score 5):

There is no other option.  `myArr["someCrazyIndexYouHaventPreviouslyUsed"]` will return undefined; an associative array will always give you `undefined` for indexes that don't exist.

So delete `myArr[someId]` will cause `myArr` to treat `someId` like every other index that doesn't exist—isn't that what you want?

Comment: According to Geuis's answer, the array stores "undefined" as an actual value, and then, with this information in your answer, it also will output undefined for any undefined index, so it's a little different.

Comment: @JVE999 whether or not `delete array[index]` stores (or displays) `undefined` depends on the implementation of the JS engine. At least as of Firefox 51.0.1,  `!function(){var x=['a','b']; console.log(x); delete x[0]; console.log(x);}()` returns 
`Array [ "a", "b" ] 
Array [ <1 empty slot>, "b" ]`