# From jQuery $.ajax to PHP: troubles accessing JSON-Values passed

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, post

Having browsed SO for hours now and tried [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105211/jquery-ajax-post-to-php) [proposed solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php) to similiar problems so as having read the [official jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), I still can't get the following code to work and would appreciate any help and hints to what I'm doing wrong.

I basically try to pass a custom JSON-object using jQuery $.ajax post to a PHP AJAX-Handler, but my PHP-Script always tells me that the data is invalid and won't execute.

#### jQuery JavaScript Code:

```
function $('#linkButton').click(function(){
    var latlng = '47.39220630060216,9.366854022435746';
    var locationData = JSON.stringify({
            from_mobile: '1',
            location: latlng
        });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax_handler.php',
        data: locationData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data); // returns 'Invalid location: ' from PHP
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

Interestingly, when I log the "locationData" json-object, it looks just fine:

```
{"from_mobile":"1","location":"47.39220630060216,9.366854022435746"}
```

#### PHP AJAX-Handler Code 'ajax_handler.php':

```
$mob = json_decode($_POST['from_mobile']);
$loc = json_decode($_POST['location']);

if(!empty($loc))
{
    echo myClass::theClassMethod($mob, $loc);
} else {
    exit('Invalid location: '.$loc);
}
```

**Can anyone here spot the issue why I can't read the JSON-Values in my PHP-Script? Any help is highly appreciated!**

Comment: Change: `data: locationData` to: `data {stuff : locationData}` (without quotes around `stuff`). Access it through $_POST['stuff']. Working now?

Comment: Amazing, you pointed me into the right direction - got it to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DarthGualin 's comment and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15081192/5750030) I got it to work successfully changing the passing (JS) & parsing (PHP) Codes as follows:

#### jQuery JavaScript Code:

Change:

```
data: { jsonData: locationData },
```

Full Code:

```
function $('#linkButton').click(function(){
    var latlng = '47.39220630060216,9.366854022435746';
    var jsonData = JSON.stringify({
            from_mobile: '1',
            location: latlng
        });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax_handler.php',
        data: { jsonData: locationData },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
});
```

#### PHP AJAX-Handler Code 'ajax_handler.php':

Change:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']); // Access Data Object
$mob = $data->{'from_mobile'}; // Access Value from json_data
```

Full Code:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST['jsonData']);
$mob = $data->{'from_mobile'};
$loc = str_replace(' ', '', $data->{'location'});

if(!empty($loc))
{
    echo myClass::theClassMethod($mob, $loc);
} else {
    exit('Invalid location: '.$loc);
}
```