# Remove an item from array using UnderscoreJS

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Say I have this code

```
var arr = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}];
```

and I want to remove the item with id = 3 from the array. Is there a way of doing this without splicing? Maye something using underscore or something like that?
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to create a new array, splicing is the only choice. I bet underscore uses it too (internally, if such a method exist).

Comment: What's wrong with splicing?

Comment: Have you checked underscore's reference?

Comment: Just using plain JavaScript, this is a duplicate of [remove objects from array by object property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16491758/218196).

Comment: well is not duplicate as it has the tag for underscore.js

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't answer this question yet, but you can use _.reject(collection, predicate, [context])(http://underscorejs.org/#reject) for this case. This method is opposite of filter, so it returns the values in list without the elements that the truth test (predicate) passes. This is exactly what you need ;)

Comment: why not `arr = arr.filter(v => v.id != 3);`? Never understand, why peoples use some kind of frameworks to do common action in javascript, using it's native api? You are afraid that your array will be `null` or `not array`? Or you trust to library more than native api, that already used inside of this library?

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Just using plain JavaScript, this has been answered already: [remove objects from array by object property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16491758/218196).

Using underscore.js, you could combine [`.findWhere`](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) with [`.without`](http://underscorejs.org/#without):

```js
var arr = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'a'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'b'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'c'
}];

//substract third
arr = _.without(arr, _.findWhere(arr, {
  id: 3
}));
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Although, since you are creating a new array in this case anyway, you could simply use `_.filter` or the native `Array.prototype.filter` function (just like shown in the other question). Then you would only iterate over array once instead of potentially twice like here.

If you want to modify the array **in-place**, you have to use `.splice`. This is also shown in the other question and undescore doesn't seem to provide any useful function for that.

Comment: Yep this works perfectly, I did go over the underscore documentation but didn't quite understand how to pull it out with without. Thank you!

Comment: Wouldn't _.reject or _.filter() be a lot more efficient here? You'd end up with two iterations of the list just to pull out one item.

Comment: This might be a duplicate but this is the better answer.

Comment: Underscore does not provide `.splice` functionality because splice is a destructive function. For further explanation, see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18363134/2479481).

Comment: @RickStrahl You are right. `_.reject` looks like a better selection here.

Comment: If ever someone want to pop last element, just simply: `_.without(arr, _.last(arr))` and for first element just use `_.first`

Comment: @lukaserat to pop the last element, use [`arr.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop?v=control)...

Answer (score 101):

You can use Underscore [`.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)

```
    var arr = [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'a'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: 'b'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'c'
    }];

    var filtered = _(arr).filter(function(item) {
         return item.id !== 3
    });
```

Can also be written as:

```
var filtered = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id !== 3
});

var filtered = _.filter(arr, function(item) {
    return item.id !== 3
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/u7F2C/)**

You can also use [`.reject`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject)

Comment: I think you meant: 

var filtered = _.filter(arr, function(item) {
     return item.id !== 3
});

Comment: @tbh__   `_()` will create a wrapper around the collection which will let you invoke underscore methods.

Comment: Been using underscore for years, I never knew this. Thanks

Answer (score 39):

Use Underscore [`_.reject()`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject):

```
arr = _.reject(arr, function(d){ return d.id === 3; });
```

Comment: with es6 you can do `arr = _.reject(arr, d => d.id === 3 );`

Answer (score 18):

Underscore has a [_without()](http://underscorejs.org/#without) method perfect for removing an item from an array, especially if you have the object to remove.

> Returns a copy of the array with all instances of the values removed.

```
_.without(["bob", "sam", "fred"], "sam");

=> ["bob", "fred"]
```

Works with more complex objects too.

```
var bob = { Name: "Bob", Age: 35 };
var sam = { Name: "Sam", Age: 19 };
var fred = { Name: "Fred", Age: 50 };

var people = [bob, sam, fred]

_.without(people, sam);

=> [{ Name: "Bob", Age: 35 }, { Name: "Fred", Age: 50 }];
```

If you don't have the item to remove, just a property of it, you can use `_.findWhere` and then `_.without`.

Comment: Note: this only works because you're passing the sam object to without. If you instead pass `{ Name: "Sam", Age: 19 }` to without, rather than the variable sam, it no longer works. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx8k13vd/)

Answer (score 6):

Please exercise care if you are filtering strings and looking for case insensitive filters. _.without() is case sensitive. You can also use _.reject() as shown below.

```
var arr = ["test","test1","test2"];

var filtered = _.filter(arr, function(arrItem) {
    return arrItem.toLowerCase() !== "TEST".toLowerCase();
});
console.log(filtered);
// ["test1", "test2"]

var filtered1 = _.without(arr,"TEST");
console.log(filtered1);
// ["test", "test1", "test2"]

var filtered2 = _.reject(arr, function(arrItem){ 
    return arrItem.toLowerCase() === "TEST".toLowerCase();
});
console.log(filtered2);
// ["test1", "test2"]
```

Answer (score 6):

Other answers create a new copy of the array, if you want to modify the array in place you can use:

```
arr.splice(_.findIndex(arr, { id: 3 }), 1);
```

But that assumes that the element will always be found inside the array (because if is not found it will still remove the last element). To be safe you can use:

```
var index = _.findIndex(arr, { id: 3 });
if (index > -1) {
    arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

or another handy way:

```
_.omit(arr, _.findWhere(arr, {id: 3}));
```

my 2 cents

Comment: omit works on `object` and returns an `object`. hence not vey good for working with `Arrays` where we might expect to get an `array` back after removing an element.

Comment: So, *_.without* is the on you're looking at:

```_.without([1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4], 0, 1);

=> [2, 3, 4]```

Answer (score 2):

Use can use **plain JavaScript**'s [**`Array#filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method like this:

```js
var arr = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}];

var filteredArr = arr.filter(obj => obj.id != 3);

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Or, use [**`Array#reduce`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**`Array#concat`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) methods like this:

```js
var arr = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}];

var reducedArr = arr.reduce((accumulator, currObj) => {
  return (currObj.id != 3) ? accumulator.concat(currObj) : accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(reducedArr);
```

NOTE:

- Both of these are pure functional approach (**i.e.** they don't modify the existing array).
- No, external library is required in these approach (Vanilla JavaScript is enough).

Answer (score 0):

I used to try this method

```
_.filter(data, function(d) { return d.name != 'a' });
```

There might be better methods too like the above solutions provided by users

Answer (score 0):

By Using underscore.js

```
var arr = [{id:1,name:'a'},{id:2,name:'b'},{id:3,name:'c'}];

var resultArr = _.reject(arr,{id:3});

console.log(resultArr);
```

The result will be :: `[{id:1name:'a'},{id:2,name:'c'}]`

Answer (score -1):

You can use reject method of Underscore, below will return a new array which won't have array with particular match

```
arr = _.reject(arr, function(objArr){ return objArr.id == 3; });
```

Answer (score -1):

[lodash](https://lodash.com/) can be used:

```
_.compact(arr);
```

Comment: Underscore has [compact](https://underscorejs.org/#compact), too. More importantly, this does not answer the question because _.compact only removes falsy values.