# Remove value from array in Underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Why isn't there a super simple `remove` function in underscore?

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
_.remove(arr, 5);
```

Sure I could use `reject` or `without`... but neither of them are destructive. Am I missing something?

I guess I'll do it the old fashioned way...

```
arr.splice(arr.indexOf(5), 1);
```

ugh

Comment: So you need to modify the original, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove item from array of objects in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994212/remove-item-from-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Explanation

This is because Underscore provides functional concepts to JavaScript, and one of the key concepts of functional programming is [Referential Transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_(computer_science)).

Essentially, functions do not have *side-effects* and will always return the same output for a given input. In other words, all functions are [pure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).

Removing an element from the array would indeed be a predictable result for the given input, but the result would be a *side-effect* rather than a return value. Thus, destructive functions do not fit into the functional paradigm.

## Solution

The correct way to remove values from an array in Underscore has already been discussed at length on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16994212/2479481). As a side note, when using `without`, `reject` or `filter`, if you only want to remove a single instance of an item from an array, you will need to uniquely identify it. So, in this manner:

```
arr = _.without(arr, 5);
```

you will remove *all* instances of `5` from `arr`.

Comment: @AaronF Good catch. I've updated my answer to call out this functionality.