# How to remove an element from an array using _.set or equivalent

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

How to remove an element using lodash/fp's `set` or equivalent method.

I tried

`_.set({data:[1,2,3]},"data[1]", undefined)`

which results in
`{data:[1,undefined,3]}` where as I would like to get the output as `{data:[1,3]}`

also tried `unset` which results in `{data:[1,empty,3]}`

Comment: why aren't you just splice ing it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove an item from array using UnderscoreJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16994212/remove-an-item-from-array-using-underscorejs)

Comment: I would prefer to use `path` instead of using predicates. The `path` can be nested and deep and splice works only on the array instance.

Comment: `splice` also mutates, while i am looking at new object which can be used in react state

Comment: do you mean something like https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper?

Comment: Also, https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/ ImmutableJS is probably what you want to be using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a clean solution for you. The only thing you need to change is the `_.isEqual(idx, 1)` for whatever index that you want to remove, or even change it and use an array, if you need by using `_.includes([1, 5, 10], idx)` instead of the `_.isEqual()` functionality.

```js
// Your idea:
_.set({data:[1,2,3]},"data[1]", undefined)

// Using a simple _.reject() function:
const newData = _.assign({}, myObj, {
  data: _.reject(myObj.data, (val, idx) => _.isEqual(idx, 1))
});
```

Comment: I can remove 2 slices and concat with this reject

Comment: I'm glad that you were able to find this useful. If you wish for this to be your answer, it would be helpful for others in the future if you were to choose this as the selected answer. Glad I could be of help!

Comment: I have upvoted the answer. I will validate it in code and once done, will mark this as an answer

Comment: Do you know how to do this with lodash fp? I am unable to get the parameter into predicate

Comment: @Ramesh => I am sorry, but I have not done much with the Lodash FP side of things. I would probably ask another question, refer to this one, and then see if you can get a Lodash FP answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using a sequence of operations.

1. used `get` to fetch the array at the specified path.
2. used `slice` to get a sliced array till specified index.
3. used `slice` to get second array after specified index.
4. used `concat` to merge first and second array.
5. used `set` to set the array at the specified path.

```
    const arrayData = get(path, state);
    if (arrayData && index < arrayData.length) {
      const firstSet = slice(0, payload.index, arrayData);
      console.log("array data after slice", arrayData);
      const secondSet = slice(payload.index + 1, arrayData.length, arrayData);

      const newState = set(
        path,
        concat(firstSet, secondSet),
        state
      );
    } else {
       return {...state}
    }
```