# How to remove array from array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array

```
var arr = [{"id":"1","name":"One"},{"id":"2","name":"Two"}]
```

I push to the array

```
arr.push(X)
```

But how can I remove for example **{"id":"1","name":"One"}** from this array by **name**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove objects from array by object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491758/remove-objects-from-array-by-object-property)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In plain javascript, you have to search through the array looking for a name match in each object and then remove that object:

```
function removeFromArrayByName(arr, name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i].name === name) {
             arr.splice(i, 1);
             return;
        }
    } 
}
```

Or if there might be more than one match and you want to remove all the matches there are, you can do this (does a backward traversal and doesn't return when it finds a match):

```
function removeFromArrayByName(arr, name) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i].name === name) {
             arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    } 
}
```

Or, you could even make it more generic where you pass in the property name to search too:

```
function removeFromArrayByName(arr, prop, val) {
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (arr[i][prop] === val) {
             arr.splice(i, 1);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is for plain js but if you use jquery, you can write a function like this:

```
function removeByName(arr, key){
   return $.grep(arr, function (n,i) {
      return n.name != key;
   });
}
```

In your case, I will call `removeByName(arr,'One');`