# Delete an object in an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm pretty new to JavaScript/AngularJS, I would like to delete an object in an object.

Let's take this for example:

```
var heroes = {
  0: { 
      name: 'Batman',
      gender: 'M'
  },
  1: {
      name: 'Superman',
      gender: 'M'
  },
  3: {
      name: 'Catwoman',
      gender: 'F'
  }
};
```

---

I would like to delete the object when `gender == 'F'`.

```
for(var hero of heroes) {
    if(hero.gender == 'F') {
        //Delete her
    }
}
```

`delete hero` does not work, I have:

> SyntaxError: applying the 'delete' operator to an unqualified name is
>   deprecated

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question: [`[javascript] remove property`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+remove+property).

Comment: Are you sure you have a `for...of` loop? They don't work with objects by default. Use `for...in`.

Comment: Nothing like an edit that changes the question from what was originally asked.

Comment: My `for...of` seems to work. The problem came on `delete hero;`. So, maybe am I iterating on an array of objects? :/

Comment: *"maybe am I iterating on an array of objects"* Well, you should know better than us :P If that's the case then it's a duplicate of [remove objects from array by object property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16491758/218196)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)

```
delete heroes[3]
```

If you do not know the key:

```
Object.keys(heroes).forEach( function (key) { //loop over the keys
    if (heroes[key].name==="Catwoman") {      //compare the name
        delete heroes[key];                   //remove the entry
    } 
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator.

> The `delete` **operator** removes a property from an object.

```
delete heroes['3'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
delete heroes[3];
```

Use above code