# Remove exact object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

With the following array:

```js
randomArray = [
  {alias: 'book1', page: 127}, 
  {alias: 'book1', page: 115}, 
  {alias: 'book2', page: 115}
]
```

If I'd like to add an object to the array, (when order doesn't matter), I'm assuming I can simply:

`randomArray.push({alias: 'book3', page: 303})`

But if I want to remove an object, say for example I would like to remove:
`{alias: 'book1', page: 115}`, how would I do this?

I've seen other stack overflow questions, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668174/indexof-method-in-an-object-array/38516944), try to find an index of the object, but they look for one property assuming that property has unique values throughout the array.

### My thought:

I wanted to try `indexOf` and then `splice` that object, but it doesn't work.

`randomArray.indexOf({alias: 'book1', page: 115})` returns `-1`

**What's an efficient way to look through an array of objects and remove an exact match?** For clarity, without using a library, and all of these objects will have the same `alias` and `id` properties, no more, no less. (Also, am I supposed to call these properties or keys, or are they synonymous?)

**Edit**: I've changed `id` to `page` to make more sense

Comment: Can you use a library ?

Comment: @LéoMartin negative. Editing the question to reflect this

Comment: Sad your id's aren't unique (?)

Comment: Use the code from that same question's answers, just amend it to look at more than one property...

Comment: @LéoMartin my Id's will be unique to the alias, but not the array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove objects from array by object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491758/remove-objects-from-array-by-object-property)

Comment: @JamesB see my solutions

Comment: Only true way to do something like you're requesting is to make your own deep equals function and then perform `Array#filter`

Comment: @Andrew my second solution does the trick the proper way imo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dirty solution (assuming the objects does not contain functions):

```js
const objectToRemove = JSON.stringify({ alias: 'pepper', id: 1 });
const filteredArray = randomArray.filter(item =>
  JSON.stringify(item) !== objectToRemove);
```

Another solution would be to build a unique ID from the objects:

```js
const toRemove = Object.entries({ alias: 'pepper', id: 1 }).join('-');
const filteredArray = randomArray.filter(item =>
  Object.entries(item).join('-') !== toRemove);
```

Or

```js
const toRemove = 'pepper-1;
const filteredArray = randomArray.filter(item =>
  `${item.alias}-${item.page}` !== toRemove);
```

Comment: Clean enough for me! I've edited the original question if you would like to edit your response to make sense for future visitors. My edits were changing the `alias`'s to `books`'s and the `id`'s to `page`'s. Will mark correct when time limit is up

Comment: Will work the same way, just update the objectToRemove accordingly :)

Answer (score -1):

JSON.stringify and joins are both very dirty solutions and both rely on the properties being in the same order, use a deep object compare function and then you can just use a filter to return an array that doesn't contain the item you want to remove.

```js
const compare = (obj1, obj2) =>
  Array.isArray(obj1)
    ? Array.isArray(obj2) && obj1.length === obj2.length && obj1.every((item, index) => compare(item, obj2[index]))
    : obj1 instanceof Date
    ? obj2 instanceof Date && obj1.getDate() === obj2.getDate()
    : obj1 && typeof obj1 === 'object'
    ? obj2 && typeof obj2 === 'object' &&
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).length === Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj2).length &&
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj1).every(prop => compare(obj1[prop], obj2[prop]))
    : obj1 === obj2;
    
const randomArray = [
  {alias: 'book1', page: 127}, 
  {alias: 'book1', page: 115}, 
  {alias: 'book2', page: 115}
];

console.log(randomArray.filter(item => !compare(item, {alias: 'book1', page: 127})));
```

Comment: Could you provide context on what "dirty solution" means? For this question, the properties will always be in the same order. I ask because this question was posted after the first answer was marked correct, and someone has downvoted it.

Comment: What an overcomplicated solution when you can simply build an unique compound index from a given object

Comment: When you already have the deep compare function in your project it is a simple solution. If you know it is just alias and page properties then it is overkill but this solution works for any array.

Comment: @LéoMartin I have used your solution. I do not understand why people are downvoting a solution (yours) that works perfectly for my given task.

Comment: Dirty means that turning objects into strings to compare them is very inefficient. If there are only two properties the most efficient solution is randomArray.filter(item => item.alias !== remove.alias && item.page !== remove.page)