# TypeError for "every" function in TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, ubuntu, typeerror

I'm working on a project that filters jobs depending on job schedules and personal availability of users.

```js
const jobs: JobRecord[] = [
  {
    "storeName": "Highwire Coffee Company",
    "schedule":  [
      "Tuesday",
      "Thursday",
    ],
        ...
  },
  {
    "storeName": "Blue Bottle Coffee",
    "rid": "recNgeUMcYhWUxw8b",
    "schedule":  [
      "Thursday",
    ],
    ...
  },
] 

const availability: Availability = {
  "friday": false,
  "monday": false,
  "thursday": true,
  "tuesday": false,
  "wednesday": true,
}
```

For example, given these inputs above, I should make a function returning only the job with storename "Blue Bottle Coffee".

To that end, I've written these two functions.

```js
  findAvailableDays (availability: Availability){
    var availDays: string[];
    availDays = [];
    for (const [day, avail] of Object.entries(availability)){
      if (avail){
        availDays.push(day);
      }
    }
    return availDays;
  };

  filterJobs = (jobs: JobRecord[], availability: Availability): void => {
    // Step 0: Clone the jobs input
    const newJobs: JobRecord[] = cloneDeep(jobs);
    console.log(newJobs, availability);

    // Step 1: Remove jobs where the schedule doesn't align with the users' availability.
    for (const[store, schedule] of Object.entries(jobs)){
      var availDays: string[];
      availDays = this.findAvailableDays(availability);
      const checkIncludes = (currentValue) => availDays.includes(currentValue);
      let checker = (availDays, schedule) => schedule.every(checkIncludes(checkIncludes));
      if(!checker(availDays, schedule)){
        delete newJobs[store];
      }
    }
    // Step 2: Save into state
    this.setState({ jobs: newJobs });
  };
```

However, my every() function in filterJobs always runs into an error (shown below). I've checked that every() accepts functions as arguments (which I made sure), and works on arrays (I believe schedule should be an array, given the example). What am I doing wrong/missing here? Should I try to find another way to go about this?

[image]

Comment: Please post your JobRecord type code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`schedule` isn’t an array, it’s a `JobRecord`. You probably meant this, where `schedule` is destructured from the `JobRecord`:

```js
for (const [store, {schedule}] of Object.entries(jobs)) {
```

However, the better way to write the whole thing is without deleting by index – use `filter` instead:

```js
filterJobs = (jobs: JobRecord[], availability: Availability): void => {
  const availDays = this.findAvailableDays(availability);

  const filteredJobs = jobs.filter(({schedule}) =>
    schedule.every(day => availDays.includes(day)));

  this.setState({ jobs: filteredJobs });
};
```

It looks like you might need to consider the case difference between the property names of `availability` and the elements of `schedule`, by the way.

Comment: that does seem to get rid of the errors I encountered previously, but fails to return "Blue Bottle Coffee" in the example case. I'm trying to figure out why—do you know why this might be the case?

Comment: @singularity: “It looks like you might need to consider the case difference between the property names of `availability` and the elements of `schedule`, by the way.” Confirm with a debugger if you have one! `console.log` otherwise.

Comment: ah, I finally see what you mean! I just tried `schedule.every(day.toLowerCase() => availDays.includes(day.toLowerCase())))`, but they don't seem to accept the change (error). Does that mean I should modify my inputs into availDays?

Comment: @singularity: The left of `=>` is the parameter list for the function. It doesn’t make sense to put an expression like `day.toLowerCase()` there. Just `schedule.every(day => availDays.includes(day.toLowerCase())))`.

Comment: thank you! I do have one more question, though. Is there any way you can modify newJobs rather than create an entirely new array? The way I was given the shell code, it seems newJobs should be modifiable, but newJobs is apparently "read-only".

Comment: @singularity: Deep cloning is a highly questionable choice on their part… anyway, see `filterInPlace` at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491758/remove-objects-from-array-by-object-property/16491790#16491790, which can be used like `filter`.