# Removing objects from [key, value] object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I'm a beginner and I'm learning, please don't close my question.

I need to filter elements with the property `toRemove:true`

```
{
  1: {itemId: 10, offset: 5, verticalPosition: 1, horizontalPosition: 35, toRemove: true},
  2: {itemId: 10, offset: 10, verticalPosition: 3, horizontalPosition: 65, toRemove: true},
  3: {itemId: 6, offset: 30, verticalPosition: 2, horizontalPosition: 109},
  4: {itemId: 8, offset: 40, verticalPosition: 5, horizontalPosition: 40},
  5: {itemId: 7, offset: 50, verticalPosition: 9, horizontalPosition: 50, toRemove: true},
  6: {itemId: 7, offset: 35, verticalPosition: 8, horizontalPosition: 77},
  7: {itemId: 7, offset: 45, verticalPosition: 7, horizontalPosition: 66}
}
```

What I expect is the key/obj as the code below.

```
{
  3: {itemId: 6, offset: 30, verticalPosition: 2, horizontalPosition: 109},
  4: {itemId: 8, offset: 40, verticalPosition: 5, horizontalPosition: 40},
  6: {itemId: 7, offset: 35, verticalPosition: 8, horizontalPosition: 77},
  7: {itemId: 7, offset: 45, verticalPosition: 7, horizontalPosition: 66}
}
```

How could I filter it?

Comment: Use 'filter' function of array, or splice if you want to modify same array.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491758/remove-objects-from-array-by-object-property/22357143#22357143

Comment: You cannot use `.filter()` on object.

Comment: if its object, 'for in' loop can be used.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @RifatBinReza I know, filter is an array function, but how could I do it in that example with object... somehow I need to iterate it...

Comment: @RahulR. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Object.keys()` to iterate through the object and delete the elements you don't want. Instead of delete, you can also add them to a new variable as well.

```js
var data = {
  1: {itemId: 10, offset: 5, verticalPosition: 1, horizontalPosition: 35, toRemove: true},
  2: {itemId: 10, offset: 10, verticalPosition: 3, horizontalPosition: 65, toRemove: true},
  3: {itemId: 6, offset: 30, verticalPosition: 2, horizontalPosition: 109},
  4: {itemId: 8, offset: 40, verticalPosition: 5, horizontalPosition: 40},
  5: {itemId: 7, offset: 50, verticalPosition: 9, horizontalPosition: 50, toRemove: true},
  6: {itemId: 7, offset: 35, verticalPosition: 8, horizontalPosition: 77},
  7: {itemId: 7, offset: 45, verticalPosition: 7, horizontalPosition: 66}
}

Object.keys(data).forEach((key)=> {
  if (data[key].toRemove) delete data[key]
})

console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `.filter()`, you can use it on [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). Then [assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) it to a new Object,

```js
let obj = {
  1: {itemId: 10, offset: 5, verticalPosition: 1, horizontalPosition: 35, toRemove: true},
  2: {itemId: 10, offset: 10, verticalPosition: 3, horizontalPosition: 65, toRemove: true},
  3: {itemId: 6, offset: 30, verticalPosition: 2, horizontalPosition: 109},
  4: {itemId: 8, offset: 40, verticalPosition: 5, horizontalPosition: 40},
  5: {itemId: 7, offset: 50, verticalPosition: 9, horizontalPosition: 50, toRemove: true},
  6: {itemId: 7, offset: 35, verticalPosition: 8, horizontalPosition: 77},
  7: {itemId: 7, offset: 45, verticalPosition: 7, horizontalPosition: 66}
};

let res = Object.assign({}, Object.values(obj).filter(e => !e.toRemove));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hello friend, thank you so much. But help me a bit more...

2 points:

- I don't need to use .filter()
- I need to keep the real ID, your example is setting 0 and auto-incrementing after

Comment: @felipemuner In that case, [@Rifat Bin Reza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6480803/rifat-bin-reza)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66634763/7575111) is better.