How can I recursively remove objects from an array and add those items to a new array?
I have an array of nested objects:
const members = [
  {
    name: 'Mike',
    type: 'MANAGER',
    children: []
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    type: 'MANAGER',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'George',
        type: 'EMPLOYEE',
        children: []
      },
      {
        name: 'Jake',
        type: 'EMPLOYEE',
        children: []
      },
      {
        name: 'Fred',
        type: 'MANAGER',
        children: [
          {
            name: 'Henry',
            type: 'EMPLOYEE',
            children: []
          },
          {
            name: 'Julie',
            type: 'MANAGER',
            children: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Alex',
    type: 'MANAGER',
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Mark',
        type: 'EMPLOYEE',
        children: []
      },
      {
        name: 'Ashley',
        type: 'MANAGER',
        children: []
      }
    ]
  }
];

How can I recursively remove all of the EMPLOYEE objects from the array and add them to a new array?
I'm able to add all of the EMPLOYEE members to a new array, but I'm not sure how to remove them from the original array.
const employees = [];

const extractEmployees = (members) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    const member = members[i];

    // add employee to employees array
    if(member.type === 'EMPLOYEE') {
      employees.push(member);
    }

    if(member.children) {
      // call function recursively for member children
      extractEmployees(member.children);
    }
  }
}

// initialize
extractEmployees(members);


You can use member.children = member.children.filter(...). The filter callback can add the children that it returns false for to the employees array.

If you iterate backwards over members (from len - 1 to 0), you can safely use members.splice(i, 1) to remove it if it's an employee.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491758/remove-objects-from-array-by-object-property/16491790#16491790

What if an employee has children? Will the collected object then have all those children included, potentially repeating a child employee that is also collected separately?

VTR, as the proposed duplicate is about a flat array, and this one is about a tree, even if it uses the wrong term in its text. Moreover, this is about both removing from the original structure and collecting the removed values in an array. In short, it's a very different question.

The extractEmployees can return a new array of members (newMembers) that doesn't include the employees. This array is assigned to the member.children:


const employees = [];

const extractEmployees = (members) => {
  const newMembers = []; // init a new array

  for(let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    const member = members[i];

    if(member.type === 'EMPLOYEE') {
      employees.push(member);
    } else { // if not employee add it to newMembers
      newMembers.push(member);
    }

    if(member.children) {
      // assign the returned array of members to current children
      member.children = extractEmployees(member.children);
    }
  }
  
  return newMembers; // return the new array of members
}

const members = [{"name":"Mike","type":"MANAGER","children":[]},{"name":"John","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"George","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Jake","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Fred","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"Henry","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Julie","type":"MANAGER","children":[]}]}]},{"name":"Alex","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"Mark","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Ashley","type":"MANAGER","children":[]}]}];

// initialize
extractEmployees(members);

console.log(members);



The previous solution replaces the original children arrays. If you want to keep the original arrays, you can save the items in another array, empty the original members and add to it non-employees:


const employees = [];

const extractEmployees = (members) => {
  const prevMembers = [...members]; // clone members
  members.length = 0; // empty the original array

  // iterate the previous members
  for(let i = 0; i < prevMembers.length; i++) {
    const member = prevMembers[i];

    if(member.type === 'EMPLOYEE') {
      employees.push(member);
    } else { // if not employee add to the original members array
      members.push(member);
    }

    if(member.children) {
      extractEmployees(member.children);
    }
  }
}

const members = [{"name":"Mike","type":"MANAGER","children":[]},{"name":"John","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"George","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Jake","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Fred","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"Henry","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Julie","type":"MANAGER","children":[]}]}]},{"name":"Alex","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"Mark","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Ashley","type":"MANAGER","children":[]}]}];

// initialize
extractEmployees(members);

console.log(members);




It is probably better practice to not collect the employees in a global variable. One way to collect them is to yield them from a generator.
The example in the question had no employees that had "children". If that is a possible scenario, then you might want to collect those employee records without those children, as those could also have employees which would be collected separately, leading to some duplication.
Finally, to filter inplace, you could use the two-index approach where items are packed at the left side of the array (when they should not be removed) and then the array length can be adapted accordingly.
Here is code that implements those ideas:


function* extractEmployees(members) {
    let length = 0;
    for (const member of members) {
        const { children, ...rest } = member; 
        if (member.type === 'EMPLOYEE') yield rest; // Without children
        else members[length++] = member;
        if (children) yield* extractEmployees(children);
    }
    members.length = length;
}

// Example call
const members = [{"name":"Mike","type":"MANAGER","children":[]},{"name":"John","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"George","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Jake","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Fred","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"Henry","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Julie","type":"MANAGER","children":[]}]}]},{"name":"Alex","type":"MANAGER","children":[{"name":"Mark","type":"EMPLOYEE","children":[]},{"name":"Ashley","type":"MANAGER","children":[]}]}];

const employees = [...extractEmployees(members)];

console.log("=== members with employees removed ===");
console.log(members);
console.log("=== the removed employees ===");
console.log(employees);



If you really want to collect the unaltered employees (even with children), then do yield member instead of yield rest.

I ended up using splice and decrementing the index, as suggested here:
remove objects from array by object property.
const employees = [];

const extractEmployees = (members) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    const member = members[i];

    if (member.type === 'EMPLOYEE') {
      const spliced = members.splice(i, 1);
      employees.push(spliced[0]);
      i--;
    }

    if (member.children) {
      extractEmployees(member.children);
    }
  }
};

extractEmployees(members);


I would think of this as two problems that we can solve individually and then wrap together in a single function.  First, how can we collect all the employee objects into an array?  Second, how can we create a tree that matches our original except that it includes no employee nodes?  Note that I don't speak here of modifiying the input; we're not barbarians!  Instead, we recursively create a new tree that matches the hierarchy of the original.  Here's one approach:


const extract = (tree) =>
  tree.flatMap((o) => o.type === "EMPLOYEE" ? [o] : extract(o.children))

const filter = (tree) =>
  tree.flatMap((o) => o.type !== "EMPLOYEE" ? [{...o, children: filter(o.children)}] : [])

const process = (members) => ({
  employees: extract(members),
  others: filter(members)
})


const members = [{name: "Mike", type: "MANAGER", children: []}, {name: "John", type: "MANAGER", children: [{name: "George", type: "EMPLOYEE", children: []}, {name: "Jake", type: "EMPLOYEE", children: []}, {name: "Fred", type: "MANAGER", children: [{name: "Henry", type: "EMPLOYEE", children: []}, {name: "Julie", type: "MANAGER", children: []}]}]}, {name: "Alex", type: "MANAGER", children: [{name: "Mark", type: "EMPLOYEE", children: []}, {name: "Ashley", type: "MANAGER", children: []}]}]

console.log(process(members))
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}



In practice, I would write this with more generic functions using the employee/non-employee tests as predicate functions used to configure my main functions, with code something more like this:
const extract = (pred) => (tree) =>
  tree.flatMap(o => pred(o) ? [o] : extract(pred)(o.children))

const filter = (pred) => (tree) =>
  tree.flatMap(o => pred(o) ? [{...o, children: filter(pred)(o.children)}] : [])

const process = (members) => ({
  employees: extract(({type}) => type === 'EMPLOYEE')(members),
  others: filter(({type}) => type !== 'EMPLOYEE')(members)
})

or even more likely, with named predicate functions, like this:
const extract = (pred) => (tree) =>
  tree.flatMap(o => pred(o) ? [o] : extract(pred)(o.children))

const filter = (pred) => (tree) =>
  tree.flatMap(o => pred(o) ? [{...o, children: filter(pred)(o.children)}] : [])

const isEmployee = ({type}) => type === 'EMPLOYEE'

const nonEmployee = ({type}) => type !== 'EMPLOYEE'

const process = (members) => ({
  employees: extract(isEmployee)(members),
  others: filter(nonEmployee)(members)
})

All these versions do depend upon the employee nodes having no children.  If they did, then we'd have to determine the desired output when we remove an employee node that has any non-employee child nodes.
