# How to remove array objects having property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What is the easiest way to remove **all** objects from an array with a particular property = x?

Comment: What kind of array? Sample please

Comment: _.without(array, [*values]) _.without([1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 1, 4], 0, 1);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove array element based on object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.filter`

```
var result = _.filter(arr, function(item) {
  return !("prop" in item);
});
```

If you want to limit it to the immediate properties of each item, use

```
var result = _.filter(arr, function(item) {
  return !item.hasOwnProperty("prop");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the easiest way would be to use the [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) method:

```
var newArray = _.filter(oldArray, function(x) { return !('prop' in x); });
// or
var newArray = _.filter(oldArray, function(x) { return !_.has(x, 'prop'); });
```

Or alternatively, the [`reject`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject) method should work just as well:

```
var newArray = _.reject(oldArray, function(x) { return 'prop' in x; });
// or
var newArray = _.reject(oldArray, function(x) { return _.has(x, 'prop'); });
```

---

**Update** Given your updated question, the code should look like this:

```
var newArray = _.filter(oldArray, function(x) { return x.property !== 'value'; });
```

Or like this

```
var newArray = _.reject(oldArray, function(x) { return x.property === 'value'; });
```