# Remove all keys that have the same value in array

Tags: javascript

I need to remove all keys except last inserted that have the same value on key `id_ask` in array but I'm learning javascript and I still do not know how to do this.

```
jQuery(function()
{
    let arr = []
    let q = []
    $("body").on('click', '.link_resposta', function(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        /* Act on the event */

        let id_poll = $(this).data("idpesquisa")
        let id_ask = $(this).data("idpergunta")
        let id_anwser = $(this).children("li").data("idresposta")
        let q = {
            id_poll, 
            id_ask, 
            id_anwser
        }

        arr.push(q)

        console.log(arr)
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: SO is not a code writing service, you try something and come here with a question related to a specific issue. Not "I need this done and I don't know how". if you want to "learn" javascript then you need to put in the effort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove array objects having property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738516/how-to-remove-array-objects-having-property)

Comment: I believe he could have multiples `id_ask` and want the latest object for each one. In this case, maybe a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) or an object that maps each `id_ask` to the latest object could be better than store multiple answers for the same `id_ask` in an array and then get the latest ones, unless you want they for some special reason.

Comment: Please post sample data as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of `Set`, `Array.reverse()` and `Array.map` we can solve this easily.

We first use the [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and we `map` our source array in, just feeding the `id_ask` field. From that we get an array of unique `id_ask`.

We then `map` the unique `id_ask` array and for each `id_ask` we call a `find()` on the source array in `reverse`.

Comments inline.

```js
const sampleArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    id_ask: 2,
    id_answer: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    id_ask: 2,
    id_answer: 5
  },
    {
    id: 3,
    id_ask: 3,
    id_answer: 3
  },
    {
    id: 4,
    id_ask: 3,
    id_answer: 1
  },
    {
    id: 5,
    id_ask: 4,
    id_answer: 3
  }
];

// Create a unique Set of Ask ID               
const uniqueAskId = [...new Set(sampleArray.map(e => e.id_ask))]; 
console.log(uniqueAskId);

// Use Map and Reverse to get last item.
const r = uniqueAskId.map(uid => sampleArray.reverse().find(ask => ask.id_ask === uid));
console.log(r);
```

Here it is as a single statement:

```js
const sampleArray = [
  {
    id: 1,
    id_ask: 2,
    id_answer: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    id_ask: 2,
    id_answer: 5
  },
    {
    id: 3,
    id_ask: 3,
    id_answer: 3
  },
    {
    id: 4,
    id_ask: 3,
    id_answer: 1
  },
    {
    id: 5,
    id_ask: 4,
    id_answer: 3
  }
];

// put together in a single statement.
const result = [...new Set(sampleArray.map(e => e.id_ask))]
               .map(uid => sampleArray.reverse().find(ask => ask.id_ask === uid));

console.log(result);
```

**NOTE:** For large datasets it would obviously be more efficient to call the `reverse()` one time before you use.

```
const revArray = myArray.reverse();
const resultArray = [...new Set(revArray.map(e => e.id_ask))]
           .map(uid => revArray.reverse().find(ask => ask.id_ask === uid));
```

Comment: Very thanks for spend your precious time with my question. May be universe repay you double.