# How to remove item from JS object with specific id

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In a given Javascript object I want to remove item with id#4. How can I do that?

```
var myObj =[
   {id: 1, name: "Maria"},
   {id: 2, name: "Josef"},
   {id: 3, name: "Jesus"},
   {id: 4, name: "Mohammad"}
]
```

something like
delete myObj.id = 4??

thx in advance...

Comment: You do realize that javascript object is completely invalid ?

Comment: I think your example has error. Can you change it ?

Comment: You (probably) mean: `[{id : 1, name : 'Maria'}]`, right? An object of objects would require each object to be mapped to a specific key, an *array* of objects would be easier.

Comment: Have you looked at this question, yet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property

Comment: Thank you David Thomas - I think your link is what im looking for

Comment: Just to clafify, you can have myObj be an object of objects, rather than an array of objects like you started, but you need to key them.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go back to your original question of deleting an object from your object.

Let's say you created your object as:

```js
var myObj = {};

var key = 1;
myObj[key] = {id: key, name: "Maria"};

key = 2;
myObj[key] = {id: key, name: "Josef"}

key = 3;
myObj[key] = {id: key, name: "Jesus"}

key = 4;
myObj[key] = {id: key, name: "Mohammad"}
```

which would look like:

```js
var myObj ={
   1: {id: 1, name: "Maria"},
   2: {id: 2, name: "Josef"},
   3: {id: 3, name: "Jesus"},
   4: {id: 4, name: "Mohammad"}
};
```

Then you could delete an object from your object using it's key

```js
key = 4;

delete myObj[key];
```

In this case you can `key` off of any value you want and not have to worry about filtering.