# How to remove array from multi dimensional array of javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
[
   Object { column_name="a", id=0, name="Jack"},
   Object { column_name="b", id=1, name="rose1"},
   Object { column_name="c", id=2, name="rose2"},
   Object { column_name="d", id=3, name="rose3"},
   Object { column_name="e", id=4, name="rose4"},
]
```

Above the code my array of jQuery or JavaScript.

How to remove an array of any index from multi dimensional array with JavaScript or jQuery

Suppose i want to remove 3 number of array how to remove.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. It is difficult to understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to remove the object at index 3? Also, where does jQuery come into the picture?

Comment: how can you have +5k rep

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove specific element from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/remove-specific-element-from-an-array)

Comment: And/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property

Answer (score 3):

See [.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method.

```
var array = [
    Object { column_name="a", id=0, name="Jack"},
    Object { column_name="b", id=1, name="rose1"},
    Object { column_name="c", id=2, name="rose2"}
    Object { column_name="d", id=3, name="rose3"}
    Object { column_name="e", id=4, name="rose4"}
];
var indexToRemove = 3;
array.splice(indexToRemove, 1);
```