# remove and replace item from object in array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have read and tried all of the posts of SO on this subject, but for some reason none of the answers are providing the desired effect.

I have written a shopping basket program and once the user clicks the'Buy now' button I wish to make POST request containing an object with the users order.

**Problem**

The user has the option to purchase three different items. Each time the user clicks on an item, which is a html input box, to increase the amount they wish to purchase I want to update the object to only contain the latest amount chosen.

In its simplest format the basket, when initiated, looks like this :

```
 var basket = {items:[
                    {item:"Trousers", quantity:1, cost:"10"},
                    {item:"Trainers", quantity:1, cost:"5"},
                    {item:"Jacket", quantity:1, cost:"30"}
                ]}
```

Each time the user clicks the input button I wish for the basket to be updated so if the user clicked to increase the jacket to a quantity of 3, and the trousers to 4 I want the object to look like this:

```
 var basket = {items:[
                        {item:"Trousers", quantity:4, cost:"40"},
                        {item:"Trainers", quantity:1, cost:"5"},
                        {item:"Jacket", quantity:3, cost:"90"}
                    ]}
```

Then if a user decides to reduce the number of trousers by 1, to 3, I would want the basket.items object to look like this:

```
 var basket = {items:[
                            {item:"Trousers", quantity:3, cost:"30"},
                            {item:"Trainers", quantity:1, cost:"5"},
                            {item:"Jacket", quantity:3, cost:"90"}
                        ]}
```

I have written the code for all the calculations etc. so this is not the issue but the issue is to update `basket.items` to only contain the three items listed above at once, with the latest data.

I cannot use the filter method as this needs to work in older versions of IE. I have tried all solutions listed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024866/remove-object-from-array-using-javascript) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property) along with many more but none of these answers are providing the solution I am looking for.

Let me know if any further information is required.

Comment: Have you considered using [a polyfill for `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Polyfill)?

Comment: thanks Jeroen. i didnt know about this. However, even with filter I could still not reach the desired effect. But ideally i didnt want to use this, and was hoping to reach an alternative soultion

Comment: change the data structure basket = {items : { item_a : { q : 1, cost : 10 } } }

Comment: @elio.d appreciate the response. how do you mean? could you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
var basket = {
    items: [

    {
        item: "Trousers",
        quantity: 1,
        cost: "10"
    }, {
        item: "Trainers",
        quantity: 1,
        cost: "5"
    }, {
        item: "Jacket",
        quantity: 1,
        cost: "30"
    }]
};

function updateBasket(item) {
    basket.items = basket.items.map(function (product) {
        if (product.item == item.item) return item;
        else return product;
    });
}

updateBasket({
    item: "Jacket",
    quantity: 9,
    cost: "30"
});
updateBasket({
    item: "Trainers",
    quantity: 9,
    cost: "30"
});
console.log(basket)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works the first time , but afterwards I am getting the following message:```Cannot read property 'map' of undefined```

Comment: thanks man, it should work fine only for updating the card. all calculations about quantity you should do with other functions ;)

Comment: the other calculations are sorted, so have got to where I wanted to

Answer (score 0):

- Cost should be a number and not string.
- If you are not keeping a global object for what is the price of 1 item then once you have updated your `basket` object you will loose the information on price of 1 item and you wouldn't know how much to increase the price.

Considering same, below would be my recommendation of changes:

```
 var basket = {items:[
                        {item:"Trousers", quantity:4, itemCost:40, totalCost:40},
                        {item:"Trainers", quantity:1, itemCost:5, totalCost:5},
                        {item:"Jacket", quantity:3, itemCost:90, totalCost:90},
                    ]}

function updateQuantity(itemName, qIncreaseBy, qDecreaseBy){
    console.log(basket);
    for(var propt in basket.items){
        if(basket.items[propt].item == itemName){
            if(qIncreaseBy != 0){
                basket.items[propt].quantity = (basket.items[propt].quantity + 1);
                basket.items[propt].totalCost = (basket.items[propt].totalCost + basket.items[propt].itemCost);
            } else{
                basket.items[propt].quantity = (basket.items[propt].quantity - 1);
                basket.items[propt].totalCost = (basket.items[propt].totalCost - basket.items[propt].itemCost);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(basket);
}
```

Usage:

```
updateQuantity("Trainers", 0, 1);  //To add item
updateQuantity("Trainers", 1, 0)  //To remove item
```

Comment: thank you, but this doesnt update the cost for me, and also if the user decreases the amount it doesnt provide the desired result

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Got it buddy, please see my edit of original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if for you having an array of objects is mandatory if that's not the case you can structure your data differently, for instance

```
basket = { items : { item_1 : { quantity: 1, cost: 1 } } }
```

so updating the basket it will be simply

```
function updateBasket(item, value) {
  // item -> item_1
  // value - > { quantity: 2, cost: 2}
  basket['items'][item] = value;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not working. Is the syntax definitely correct?

Comment: is the syntax for basket correct? I may be wrong but is it missing a ```:```

Comment: thanks, appreciate the help. The solution provied by Nikolay above worked

Comment: the only problem with that solutions is that you have to loop trough all the basket O(n).

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think the problem could be solved if you kept your data in a little different way. For example, something like this

```
var products  = {
    trousers:0,
    jackets:0,
    trainers:0,
};

var prices = {
    trainers:5,
    jackets: 30,
    trousers: 10
}


//to increase the amount of products after user event
products.jackets  +=2;
products.trainers +=3;
products.trousers +=1;

//finally generate your desired format
var basket = {items:[]};

for(product in products){
   basket.items.push({
       item: product,
       quantity: products[product],
       cost: products[product]*prices[product]
   });
}

console.log(basket);
```

You can see that basket is now in your desired format :)