# deleting a object of an Array based on property of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array like this: `var obj = [{x:4, y:5}, {x:6, y:2}, ...]` and I'm trying to delete one of the inside objects (properties) based on the x.

this is How I'm trying to do this:

```
 obj.forEach(function (child){
    if(child.x === 4){
      obj.destroy(child)
    }
 });
```

But it's not working and i get

> obj.destroy is not a funtion

I also tried `obj.splice(child)` but it just mess up the array. so what am doing wrong here?
Also is there a better way to do this by not having to loop through all of Array property every time?

Comment: Your original object is invalid. Did you really try creating it in JavaScript?

Comment: Javascript objects have _keys_, yours doesn't.

Comment: Don't you mean "Delete object from objects array based on property" ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i'm assuming your trying to filter out objects in an array which have an `x` that matches a given value. If thats the case, you should probably use the `filter` method.

So assuming thats what you mean you could do the following

```
obj = obj.filter(function (child){
if(child.x !== 4){
  return obj
}
});
// shorter
obj = obj.filter( child => child.x !== 4 );
```

In this case, only the objects which do not have the value of 4 will be available to you in the `obj` variable. And all other objects (assuming there are no other references in your code) will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use filter on the array: e.g.

```js
let arrayToFilter = [ {x:4, y:5}, {x:6, y:2}];
const valueToFilter = 4;

var filteredArray = arrayToFilter .filter((o) => {
    return o.x !== valueToFilter;
});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach()` works on array.

If `obj` is an array, you can simply use `filter()` to remove the unwanted object from the array:

```js
var obj = [{x:4, y:5}, {x:6, y:2}]

obj = obj.filter(c => c.x !== 4)
 
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps, have an array as `obj` because the one you posted in the question is simply invalid syntax.

Moreover, you can use `Array#findIndex` to get the index of the matching element first, and then `splice` that index from the array.

```js
var obj = [{x:4, y:5}, {x:6, y:2}];
var index = obj.findIndex(item => item.x === 4);
obj.splice(index, 1);

console.log(obj);
```