# List items are removed from bottom to top but not from top to bottom

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, splice

I made a list of items which are taken on the link. Near each element there is a button to delete when clicked on which the element should be removed from the site and api. The fact is that when I click on the delete button, everything is normal from the api, and from the site, if you delete the elements from the bottom up, it is normal, and if from top to bottom, it does not work correctly. I understand that the matter is in the splice parameters, but I do not know how to fix it.

[Screenshot of list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Ji5.png)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(post, id) of posts">
        <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
        <button  @click="deleteData(post.id)">Delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  data () {
    return{
      posts: [],
    }
  },

    created(){
      axios.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(response => {
        this.posts = response.data
      })
    },
    methods: {
        deleteData(id) {
          axios.delete('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
                    .then(response => {
                      console.log('delete')
                        this.posts.splice(id-1, 1)
                      })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
                  },
                }
              }
</script>
```

Comment: you should re-fetch the posts immediately after you delete one. Your indexes become out of sync between what you call the 'site' and the api in the code provided above.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: A better way of removing the post would be by getting the index manually (with `findIndex` for example), instead of trying to link index with id: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49689914/3499595

Comment: Replace: `this.posts.splice(id-1,1)` with `this.created();`, Done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This `id` here is actually the index, not really the `post.id`, whereas [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Syntax) takes a start **index**, see the signature [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Syntax):

```vue
<li v-for="(post, id) of posts">
<!----------------^^--- This is essentially posts[index] -->
```

So try doing the following instead:

```vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(post, index) of posts">
        <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ post.body }}</p>
        <button @click="deleteData(index, post.id)">Delete</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

```vue
methods: {
  deleteData(index, id) {
    axios
      .delete('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/' + id)
      .then(response => {
        this.posts.splice(index, 1);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  },
}
```