# typescript array remove item if condition matches

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an interface with some fields like that:

```js
interface Item {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

And I want to implement a method `removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string)` which removes all items from the given array, which have the given name:

```js
const myItems: Item[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 3, name: 'bar' }
];

removeItemsWithName(myItems, 'foo');
console.log(myItems);
```

The result should be:

```
[{id: 3, name: 'bar'}]
```

Is there a method `array.removeIf()` (like [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) in Java 8) available in typescript/javascript, so that my method could look like something similar to this:

```js
function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): void {
    items.removeIf(i => i.name === name);
}
```

I already found the question [Remove array element based on object property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15287865/9662601), but I need to modify the original array in place instead of creating a new one (like `array.filter()` does). I also want to remove all items matching the condition, not just the first one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove array element based on object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I already noticed that question before, but forgot to mention this in my question. I edited my post now to clarify it.

Comment: I notice array question always gets more answers than others :P

Comment: There are more answers on that question than the accepted one. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15287919/215552) for instance, uses `splice` in a loop.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for referencing this, I must have missed that answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The standard solution would be [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), but this returns a *new* array:

```
function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): Item[] {
  return items.filter(i => i.name !== name);
}
```

However, if you really need to modify the array in place, you'd have to use something like this:

```
function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): void {
  let j = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    const item = items[i];
    if (item.name !== name) {
        items[j] = item;
        j++;
    }
  }

  items.length = j;
}
```

Or with [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].name === name) {
      items.splice(i--, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use a library like lodash which has a convenient [`remove`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#remove) method:

```
import _remove from 'lodash/remove';

function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): void {
  _remove(items, x => x.name === name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Too many ways to do this, I suggest use `filter` function.

Try this:

```
function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): void {
  items = items.filter(i => i.name !== name);
}
```

I think it will be better if `removeItemsWithName` function returns a new array and does not change params value.

```
function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): Item[] {
  return items.filter(i => i.name !== name);
}

const myItems: Item[] = [
  { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'foo' },
  { id: 3, name: 'bar' }
];

const filtered = removeItemsWithName(myItems, 'foo');
console.log(filtered);
```

**Update**

You can create your owner `Collection` with `removeIf` method.

```
interface Item {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

class MyCollection<T> {
  private items: Array<T>;

  constructor(init?: T[]) {
    this.items = init || [];
  }

  get(): T[] {
    return this.items;
  }

  removeIf(conditionFunction: (i: T) => boolean) {
    this.items = this.items.filter(i => !conditionFunction(i));
  }
}

const myItems: MyCollection<Item> = new MyCollection<Item>([
  { id: 1, name: "foo" },
  { id: 2, name: "foo" },
  { id: 3, name: "bar" }
]);

function removeItemsWithName<T extends Item>(
  items: MyCollection<T>,
  name: string
): void {
  items.removeIf(i => i.name === name);
}

removeItemsWithName(myItems, "foo");
console.log(myItems.get());
```

Comment: What if mutating the original array is a requirement? Like stated in OP by `removeItemsWithName(...): void`

Comment: @hackape overwrite original array value, `items = removeItemsWithName(myItems, 'foo')`

Comment: @hoangdv thanks for your answer, but overwriting the original array is not an option. I need to modify the given array.

Comment: @hoangdv you miss the point, keeping the original array reference is a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.prototype.filter` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
const myItems = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'foo'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'bar'
  }
];

console.log(myItems.filter((item) => item.name !== 'foo'))
```

So your function would simply be:

```js
const removeItemsWithName = (items: Item[], name: string): Item[] => items.filter((item: Item) => item.name !== name);
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Unfortunately I need to modify the given array and can not create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Take one, leverage `.filter()`. Less code but O(2n).

```
function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): void {
  var newArray = items.filter(i => i.name !== name);
  items.length = 0; // this empty the original array
  newArray.forEach(item => { items.push(item) });
}
```

Take two, use `.splice()`, the old school O(n) way.

```
function removeItemsWithName(items: Item[], name: string): void {
  var index = items.length - 1;
  var predicate = i => i.name === name;
  while(index >= 0) {
    if (predicate(items[index])) {
      items.splice(index, 1)
    }
    index--;
  }
}
```