# Delete specific object with id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I have an array of objects, I need to delete a complete object based on the id

Input :

```
 filters: [
    {
      key: "status",
      label: "En attente",
      value: "waiting",
      id: 0
    },
    {
      key: "dateDue[min]",
      label: "15/12/2019",
      value: "15/12/2019",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      key: "dateDue[max]",
      label: "02/02/2020",
      value: "02/02/2020",
      id: 2
    },
    {
      key: "bien",
      values: [
        {
          label: "Studio Bordeaux",
          value: 36,
          id: 3
        },
        {
          label: "Studio 2",
          value: 34,
          id: 184
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: "type",
      values: [
        {
          type: "receipts",
          label: "Loyer",
          value: "loyer",
          id: 4
        },
        {
          type: "receipts",
          label: "APL",
          value: "apl",
          id: 5
        },
        {
          type: "spending",
          label: "taxes",
          value: "taxes",
          id: 6
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

So I created a removeItem method with the id that must be deleted in parameters

removeItem method :

```
removeItem = (e, id) => {
const { filters } = this.state;

const remove = _.reject(filters, el => {
  if (!_.isEmpty(el.values)) {
    return el.values.find(o => o.id === id);
  }
  if (_.isEmpty(el.values)) {
    return el.id === id;
  }
});
this.setState({
  filters: remove
});
```

};

I use lodash to make my job easier and more specifically _.reject
My issue is the following :
I manage to correctly delete the classic objects for example

```
{
  key: "status",
  label: "En attente",
  value: "waiting",
  id: 0
}
```

but my method however does not work for objects of the following form

```
   {
      key: "bien",
      values: [
        {
          label: "Studio Bordeaux",
          value: 36,
          id: 3
        },
        {
          label: "Studio 2",
          value: 34,
          id: 184
        }
      ]
    },
```

currently the whole object is deleted and not only the object in the values array according to its id

[Here is my codesandbox!](https://codesandbox.io/embed/agilimo-filters-l7q98?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

thank you in advance for your help

**EDIT**

I found a solution with lodash (compact), I share my solution here :

```js
  removeIdFromCollection = id => {
    const { filters } = this.state;
    const newFilters = [];
    _.map(filters, filter => {
      if (filter.values) {
        const valuesTmp = _.compact(
          _.map(filter.values, value => {
            if (value.id !== id) return value;
          })
        );
        if (!_.isEmpty(valuesTmp)) {
          return newFilters.push({
            key: filter.key,
            values: valuesTmp
          });
        }
      }
      if (filter.id && filter.id !== id) return newFilters.push(filter);
    });
    return newFilters;
  };

  removeItem = id => e =>
    this.setState({
      filters: this.removeIdFromCollection(id)
    });
```

The values false, null, 0, "", undefined, and NaN are removed with lodash compact (_.compact(array))

Here is my updated codesandbox

[image: Edit agilimo-filters]

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to filter the `filters` array and each `values` separately. Below is a recursive function which will remove items with the given id from the filters array and from the `values` property.

PS. This example is not using Lodash as I think it is not needed in this case.

```js
  removeIdFromCollection = (collection, id) => {
    return collection.filter(datum => {
      if (Array.isArray(datum.values)) {
        datum.values = this.removeIdFromCollection(datum.values, id);
      }

      return datum.id !== id;
    });
  }

  removeItem = (e, id) => {
    const { filters } = this.state;

    this.setState({
      filters: this.removeIdFromCollection(filters, id),
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem would be the structure of the object. You'll need to refactor for that inconvenient array out of nowhere for uniformity:

```
// Example
filters: [
...
{
  key: "type",
  values: [
    {
      type: "receipts",
      label: "Loyer",
      value: "loyer",
      id: 4
    },
    ...
  ]
...
}

// could be

filters: [
...
{
 key: "type-receipts",
 label: "Loyer",
 value: "loyer",
 id: 4
}
...
]
```

Repeat the pattern on all of it so you could just use the native array filter like this:

```
const newFilters = filters.filter(v => v.id !== id);

this.setState({
  filters: newFilters,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with lodash, I share it with you here :

```js
  removeIdFromCollection = id => {
    const { filters } = this.state;
    const newFilters = [];
    _.map(filters, filter => {
      if (filter.values) {
        const valuesTmp = _.compact(
          _.map(filter.values, value => {
            if (value.id !== id) return value;
          })
        );
        if (!_.isEmpty(valuesTmp)) {
          return newFilters.push({
            key: filter.key,
            values: valuesTmp
          });
        }
      }
      if (filter.id && filter.id !== id) return newFilters.push(filter);
    });
    return newFilters;
  };

  removeItem = id => e =>
    this.setState({
      filters: this.removeIdFromCollection(id)
    });
```

Here is my updated codesandbox

[image: Edit here]