# Removing object with property in array leaves an empty object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to remove an item with a property from array object based on the key but it is leaving an empty object. For example,

```
var items = [{"fruits": ["Apple","Banana"]},{"veggies": ["Potato","Carrot"]}]
```

So I want to remove the item with the fruits property. This is the code I tried...

```
var filter = items.map(({ fruits, ...rest }) => rest);
```

This gave me an output of

```
[{},{"veggies": ["Potato", "Carrot"]}]
```

Why is it leaving a trace of an empty object? And how to get rid of that empty object?

Comment: Why is `items` an array of objects with a single property, rather than one object with multiple properties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove array element based on object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property) Instead of `obj.property == "value"` or `obj.property != "value"`, just use `!obj.property` or `!obj.hasOwnProperty("property")`

Comment: Is that the wrong way of using array of objects? @Ivar

Comment: @HereticMonkey That provides one solution but I also wanted to know why it is leaving an empty object?

Comment: Because you're removing the `fruits` property from the object, not the object from the array.

Comment: Yeah now I know why. Thank you :)

Comment: @eerily There might be valid use cases for it, but an object _is_ a collection of properties. It doesn't make much sense to split them up into one object per property and then add them all to an array. WIth a single property, the destructuring, or simply `delete items.fruits` would've been enough. Now you need extra, potentially unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.map` will return an array of the same length, mapped to a new array.  To remove entries use `.filter`:

```js
var items = [{"fruits": ["Apple","Banana"]},{"veggies": ["Potato","Carrot"]}]
var filter = items.filter(i => !i.fruits);
console.log(filter);
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use filter function.

```js
var items = [{"fruits": ["Apple","Banana"]},{"veggies": ["Potato","Carrot"]}];
const result = items.filter(val => !val.hasOwnProperty("fruits"));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```js
var items = [{"fruits": ["Apple","Banana"]},{"veggies": ["Potato","Carrot"]}]

console.log(items.filter(item => !item.hasOwnProperty('fruits')))
```