# Return array of objects with respect to uniqueness of property: Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I am having array of objects with the following structure

```
const arr = [
              {id: 0, name: "abc", userid: "0"},
              {id: 1, name: "lmn", userid: "123"},
              {id: 3, name: "pqr", userid:"456"},
              {id: 4, name: "xyz", userid: "123"}
            ]
```

I want to return the objects where userid should be unique and is not equals to "0".

This is my approach. It returns just everything

```
   const result = [
        ...new Set(
             arr.map((node) => {
            if (node.userid !== "0") return node;
          })
        )
      ];
      console.log(result);
```

Comment: You would need to fix your input structure first. You have badly matching quotes. Secondly, use `filter` instead of `map`.

Comment: Combine [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects) and [Remove array element based on object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287865/remove-array-element-based-on-object-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Set`, use `Map`. Both are used to store unique values, the difference between them is `Set` for arrays with unique values while `Map` for objects with unique keys.

```
const arr = [
  {id: 0, name: "abc", userid: "0"},
  {id: 1, name: "lmn", userid: "123"},
  {id: 3, name: "pqr", userid: "456"},
  {id: 4, name: "xyz", userid: "123"}
];
const result = new Map()
arr.forEach(node => {
  if(node.userid !== "0"){
    result.set(node.userid,node);
  }
})
console.log([...result.values()]); // log intended results
```

For shorthanded solution you can use:

```
const result = [...new Map(arr.filter(node=>node.userid!=="0").map(node=>[node.userid, node])).values()];
console.log(result) // log intended results
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that might me done in a more short-hand way, but it works this way:

```
const arr = [
          {id: 0, name: "abc", userid: "0"},
          {id: 1, name: "lmn", userid: "123"},
          {id: 3, name: "pqr", userid: "456"},
          {id: 4, name: "xyz", userid: "123"}
        ];

const clearZero = arr.filter((obj) => obj.id != 0);
const finalArray = [];

clearZero.forEach((obj) => {
  if (finalArray.every((elem) => elem.userid !== obj.userid)) {
    finalArray.push(obj);
  }
})

console.log(finalArray); // logs out no. 1 and no.3
```

Comment: Basically, **every** method is very handy in checking through all of the elements in the array. With that, we can check if a looped element from clearZero array has the same userid as any of the elements from the finalArray we are creating.