# Array is not getting empty

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a array `search_by_type` which is declared at the top. Now in every click I am setting the `rest_type_id` value to array which is working fine.

Now other page action is calling `get_all_restro()` function which will empty the array `search_by_type`. When again I click `restro_type_filter` class it print array which has a value that means it is not getting empty.

```
var search_by_type = new Array();

$(document).on("click",".restro_type_filter",function(){

    console.log(search_by_type);

    var rest_type_id = $(this).attr('rest_type_id');
    search_by_type.push(rest_type_id); 


});

function get_all_restro(type){

    search_by_type.length = 0;

}
```

**EDIT :**

Ok guys there is an error at function get_all_restro() - `Cannot set property 'length' of undefined` how should I solve this? Is this error is creating a problem ?

What is happening here, what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206988/how-do-i-unset-an-element-in-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empty an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232040/empty-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you build a minimal fiddle to reproduce this error ?

Comment: The problem is probably that the page action calling get_all_restro is itself not getting called. Do you know if the page action is ever called?

Comment: To people pretending you can't reset an array by setting the length to 0, here's an extract from the MDN : *"You can set the length property to truncate an array at any time."*

Comment: @dystroy please see my edit. There is an error on console

Comment: `This question may already have an answer here:` dude I have already seen that and I have told you guys this is not working in my case. Please allow people to add answer for my problem

Comment: @jbutler483 I have already saw that  question and tried too as well in my case it is not working

Comment: @RakeshShetty Make it possible for us to reproduce your problem. Use http://jsbin.com for example

Comment: Then could you provide a minimal, reproducible example, and also explain your efforts so that we're not answering something you've already tried?

Comment: @dystroy I will try to add code on fiddle it will be not excat code since it is very long code but will try to paste some of the code there

Comment: @dystroy can you look into this http://jsfiddle.net/s1jrp9x0/1/ but it is giving error `get_all_restro is not defined `

Comment: @RakeshShetty In the left menu choose "no wrap <in head>"

Comment: @RakeshShetty Looks like a problem of scope. If you define the function within `$(document).ready(function(){//here//});` it's not going to be visible outside and therefore  `onclick="get_all_restro(1);"` is going to fail.

Comment: @dystroy it is running on fiddle but in my code is not running. What is "no wrap <in head>" what should I change in my code ?

Comment: @dystroy I have not wrap inside `$(document).ready(function()`

Answer (score 0):

Try re-initializing it this:

```
search_by_type = new Array();
```

or

```
search_by_type = [];
```

Complete code:

```
function get_all_restro(type){

    search_by_type = new Array();

}
```